# Why "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate' " when I have included jquery.validate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

My code:

```
@model ColumnVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddColumn3";
    Layout = "../Shared/_layout2.cshtml";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("form").validate().settings.submitHandler = function (form) {
            alert('valid form');
            form.submit();
        };
    });

</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("addcolumn3", "Course", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <fieldset>
        <legend>ColumnVM</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

in _Layout2.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Layout.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
            @RenderBody()

</body>
</html>
```

Now the browser show the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'.
If I change the Layout=null,and add manually in the code

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It works!I don't know why.Anybody who knows?

Comment: Hiya man, I reckon your Source path ain't right, try your source with these link and that should prove the fault `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js` Hope it fits the need `:)` Link: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: thx,but it still do not work:(

Comment: We're troubleshooting JavaScript so show the _rendered_ HTML please.  Either the script was properly included or it wasn't... checking the page source in the browser and the JS console for 404 errors seems to be the next logical step.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a full virtual path for your layout page:

```
@model ColumnVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddColumn3";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout2.cshtml";
}
```

Like @Tats_innit said, it could be a path resolution error.  You could also just use the name of the layout if it is unique, as MVC will look in the Shared folder for unqualified views/layouts eventually.